# read horizontally-formatted data with hidden characters, variable row lengths and blanks to represent missing observations

Tags: r

I have been provided a data file in a format I have never seen and have been having a great deal of trouble reading the data into `SAS` even after asking a question on Stack Overflow yesterday.  Today I was able to read an example data set into `R` using the code below.  Although that `R` code is not at all efficient.  Is there a better way?

When I open the data file in `Notepad` the data appear to be in one long row that wraps back to the left side of the `Notepad` window when the data reach the maximum number of characters that `Notepad` allows in a single row.  There might be 10,000 rows of real data when I open the file in `Notepad`. The data in one of these rows are not aligned with the data in the row above it or below it.

Here is an example of how the data appear in `Notepad`:

```
  MMM  0  0            1              1 1093    0        0     3           Y2  MMM  0  0            1              1 1284    0              3       200 AN  MMM  0  0            1              1 1375    4        0     0         0  DDD  0  0            1              1 1465    0        0     4         0 Y       5  MDK  0  0            1              1 1555  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        1234             0               0 B0  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        2234    2        0               0  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        0123    2        0     2         0  AAA  ZZ000000        5      14        1234    2        0     2         0 OU  AAB  302842          5      14        2222    2        0               0 E4           A  EEE  123456          5      14        2345                             0 G9  BBB  SS234567        5      14        9999    3        0               0
```

Here is an example of how those same data appear in `gVim 7.4`:

```
  MMM  0  0            1              1 1093    0        0     3           Y2
  MMM  0  0            1              1 1284    0              3       200 AN
  MMM  0  0            1              1 1375    4        0     0         0
  DDD  0  0            1              1 1465    0        0     4         0 Y       5
  MDK  0  0            1              1 1555
  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        1234             0               0 B0
  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        2234    2        0               0
  AAB  ZZ000000        5      14        0123    2        0     2         0
  AAA  ZZ000000        5      14        1234    2        0     2         0 OU
  AAB  302842          5      14        2222    2        0               0 E4           A
  EEE  123456          5      14        2345                             0 G9
  BBB  SS234567        5      14        9999    3        0               0
```

If I use `:set list` in `gVim` I see a blue `$` at the end of every line, which presumably is how `gVim` is able to align the data in to columns.

Here is the `R` code I use to read the data and create a `data frame`:

```
setwd('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/')

my.data <- readLines('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/fake_horizontal_data_with_end_of_line_characters.txt')
my.data

var1  <- substr(my.data,  1,  5)
var2  <- substr(my.data,  6, 15)
var3  <- substr(my.data, 16, 24)
var4  <- substr(my.data, 25, 32)
var5  <- substr(my.data, 33, 39)
var6  <- substr(my.data, 40, 44)
var7  <- substr(my.data, 45, 49)
var8  <- substr(my.data, 50, 58)
var9  <- substr(my.data, 59, 64)
var10 <- substr(my.data, 65, 74)
var11 <- substr(my.data, 75, 77)
var12 <- substr(my.data, 78, 84)
var13 <- substr(my.data, 85, 89)

trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

var1  <- trim(var1 )
var2  <- trim(var2 )
var3  <- trim(var3 )
var4  <- trim(var4 )
var5  <- trim(var5 )
var6  <- trim(var6 )
var7  <- trim(var7 )
var8  <- trim(var8 )
var9  <- trim(var9 )
var10 <- trim(var10)
var11 <- trim(var11)
var12 <- trim(var12)
var13 <- trim(var13)

var1  <- ifelse(nchar(var1 ) == 0, 'my.null', var1 )
var2  <- ifelse(nchar(var2 ) == 0, 'my.null', var2 )
var3  <- as.numeric(var3)
var4  <- as.numeric(var4)
var5  <- as.numeric(var5)
var6  <- as.numeric(var6)
var7  <- as.numeric(var7)
var8  <- as.numeric(var8)
var9  <- as.numeric(var9)
var10 <- as.numeric(var10)
var11 <- ifelse(nchar(var11) == 0, 'my.null', var11)
var12 <- as.numeric(var12)
var13 <- ifelse(nchar(var13) == 0, 'my.null', var13)

my.data2 <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var13, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data2
```

Here is the resulting `data frame`:

```
      var1     var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10   var11 var12   var13
1      MMM     0  0    1   NA    1 1093    0    0    3    NA      Y2    NA my.null
2      MMM     0  0    1   NA    1 1284    0   NA    3   200      AN    NA my.null
3      MMM     0  0    1   NA    1 1375    4    0    0     0 my.null    NA my.null
4      DDD     0  0    1   NA    1 1465    0    0    4     0       Y     5 my.null
5      MDK     0  0    1   NA    1 1555   NA   NA   NA    NA my.null    NA my.null
6      AAB ZZ000000    5   14   NA 1234   NA    0   NA     0      B0    NA my.null
7      AAB ZZ000000    5   14   NA 2234    2    0   NA     0 my.null    NA my.null
8      AAB ZZ000000    5   14   NA  123    2    0    2     0 my.null    NA my.null
9      AAA ZZ000000    5   14   NA 1234    2    0    2     0      OU    NA my.null
10     AAB   302842    5   14   NA 2222    2    0   NA     0      E4    NA       A
11     EEE   123456    5   14   NA 2345   NA   NA   NA     0      G9    NA my.null
12     BBB SS234567    5   14   NA 9999    3    0   NA     0 my.null    NA my.null
13 my.null  my.null   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA my.null    NA my.null
```

The above `R` code seems too complex.  However, the problems of blank character spaces to represent missing observations and variable row lengths do not seem easy to overcome.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You want `read.fwf`. Should be easy once you specify a vector of column widths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Thomas' comment:

```
setwd('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/')

my.data3 <- read.fwf('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/fake_horizontal_data_with_end_of_line_characters.txt', 

    widths=c(5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 9, 6, 10, 3, 7, 5), 

    colClasses = c('character', 'character',   'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 
                     'numeric',   'numeric',   'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 
                   'character',   'numeric', 'character'))

my.data3

> my.data3
      V1         V2 V3 V4 V5   V6 V7 V8 V9 V10  V11 V12   V13
1    MMM   0  0      1 NA  1 1093  0  0  3  NA   Y2  NA  <NA>
2    MMM   0  0      1 NA  1 1284  0 NA  3 200   AN  NA  <NA>
3    MMM   0  0      1 NA  1 1375  4  0  0   0 <NA>  NA  <NA>
4    DDD   0  0      1 NA  1 1465  0  0  4   0   Y    5  <NA>
5    MDK   0  0      1 NA  1 1555 NA NA NA  NA <NA>  NA  <NA>
6    AAB   ZZ000000  5 14 NA 1234 NA  0 NA   0   B0  NA  <NA>
7    AAB   ZZ000000  5 14 NA 2234  2  0 NA   0 <NA>  NA  <NA>
8    AAB   ZZ000000  5 14 NA  123  2  0  2   0 <NA>  NA  <NA>
9    AAA   ZZ000000  5 14 NA 1234  2  0  2   0   OU  NA  <NA>
10   AAB   302842    5 14 NA 2222  2  0 NA   0   E4  NA     A
11   EEE   123456    5 14 NA 2345 NA NA NA   0   G9  NA  <NA>
12   BBB   SS234567  5 14 NA 9999  3  0 NA   0 <NA>  NA  <NA>
13  <NA>       <NA> NA NA NA   NA NA NA NA  NA <NA>  NA  <NA>
```

I would still need to trim the character variables if I wanted the white space removed.

**EDIT**

This appears to strip the leading and trailing white space:

```
setwd('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/')

my.data3 <- read.fwf('C:/Users/markm/simple SAS programs/fake_horizontal_data_with_end_of_line_characters.txt', 

                    widths=c(5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 9, 6, 10, 3, 7, 5), 

                    colClasses = c('character', 'character',   'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 
                                     'numeric',   'numeric',   'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 
                                   'character',   'numeric', 'character'), strip.white = TRUE)

my.data3

> my.data3
     V1       V2 V3 V4 V5   V6 V7 V8 V9 V10  V11 V12  V13
1   MMM     0  0  1 NA  1 1093  0  0  3  NA   Y2  NA <NA>
2   MMM     0  0  1 NA  1 1284  0 NA  3 200   AN  NA <NA>
3   MMM     0  0  1 NA  1 1375  4  0  0   0 <NA>  NA <NA>
4   DDD     0  0  1 NA  1 1465  0  0  4   0    Y   5 <NA>
5   MDK     0  0  1 NA  1 1555 NA NA NA  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
6   AAB ZZ000000  5 14 NA 1234 NA  0 NA   0   B0  NA <NA>
7   AAB ZZ000000  5 14 NA 2234  2  0 NA   0 <NA>  NA <NA>
8   AAB ZZ000000  5 14 NA  123  2  0  2   0 <NA>  NA <NA>
9   AAA ZZ000000  5 14 NA 1234  2  0  2   0   OU  NA <NA>
10  AAB   302842  5 14 NA 2222  2  0 NA   0   E4  NA    A
11  EEE   123456  5 14 NA 2345 NA NA NA   0   G9  NA <NA>
12  BBB SS234567  5 14 NA 9999  3  0 NA   0 <NA>  NA <NA>
13 <NA>     <NA> NA NA NA   NA NA NA NA  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
```